# Django views/class naming conventions

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, naming-conventions

Just recently i changed my IDE to PyCharm (former was Sublime) and turns out all my views/classes are considered bad because they have underscore ( _ ) in their name.

My django-rest project views goes as follows:

```py
    # BuyersProject
    path('bproject/', views.BP_List.as_view()), # Create BP | List user's BP
    path('bproject/active/', views.BP_LastActive.as_view()), # Get last active BP
    path('bproject/<int:pk>/', views.BP_Detail.as_view()), # Get specific BP
    path('bproject/<int:pk>/filter/', views.BP_UpdateFilter.as_view()), # Update BP's filter
    path('bproject/<int:pk>/step/', views.BP_StatusUpdate.as_view()), # BP status update

    # BuyersProjectDetail
    path('bproject/<int:pk>/detail/', views.BPD_List.as_view()), # BP's BPD List
    path('bproject/detail/<int:pk>/', views.BPD_Detail.as_view()), # BPD Detail
    path('bproject/detail/<int:pk>/close/', views.BPD_Close.as_view()), # Close BPD

    # SellersProject
    path('sproject/', views.SP_List.as_view()), # Create SP | List user's SP
    path('sproject/<int:pk>/', views.SP_Detail.as_view()), # Get specific SP
    path('sproject/<int:pk>/bc/', views.SP_BC_SellerUpdate.as_view()), # Update SP's BC
    path('sproject/<int:pk>/step/', views.SP_StatusUpdate.as_view()), # SP status update
```

*BP, BPD, SP, SPD and BC are achronyms for some of my models*

My question: is it really that bad to have underscore in the name? should i rename my classes to match with naming conventions?

I am a strong believer that code should be readable for humans more than for machines.

> "Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.” – Martin Fowler

I do care a lot about documenting, formatting and code structure/conventions (when working in a team it's really important) so i'm open to change if my current code is bad.
Also, any advice/comment you make about the endpoints, views name or comments will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

items in *PascalCase* usually do *not* have underscores (`_`), that is for *snake_case*, but snake case is written in *lowercase*.

For classes, [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) advises to use PerlCase:

> Class names should normally use the *CapWords* convention.

so it should be `BPList`, not `BP_List`.

Furthermore in Django, class-based views usually have a `…View` suffix. so you might want to rename `BP_List` to `BPListView`.

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer, i understand the convention but i don't want to follow it blindly (mostly bc my views (only views) would end up having a long messy name that is hardly readable like `AdminBPDReactiveView`, and that's the main reason i started using the model sufix in some of them like `Admin_BPD_Reactive`, on top of that views would never be seen anywhere other than the views file and urls, so i don't really understand the need for the `View` sufix. (maybe i didn't made my point clear, i want reasons on why to use the conventions instead of my already formatted code)

Comment: @psirohyarte_7: the reason why a `...View`, `...Form`, `...Admin`, `...FilterSet`, etc. is added is because often people tend to give it the same name as the model, form, etc. I often see people that define a model `Posts`, and then define a view `Posts`, or a form `AddPost` that is used in the `AddPost` view, and this results in a lot of bugs due to the clash of the identifiers. With modern IDEs, one can easily write identifiers without a lot of keyboard strokes and therefore clear nomenclature will usually result in better code.